# Fail to understand elementary matrices properties in matrix LU factorization.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am reading about $LU$ factorization for the first time. I encounter a theorem that says that if we can obtain a upper-triangular row equal matrix $U$ from matrix $A$ with elementary matrices call them $E_1,E_2,\ldots,E_k$ that are not row interchanged then we can have $LU$ factorization. The reason for not interchanging rows as said is to keep $E_i$ matrices lower-triangular. I think if we never interchange rows but for example add $s$ times of row $2$ to row $1$ we contract the lower-triangularity of $E_i$ matrices too, but this operator didn't forbid in the theorem as you see.

Thank you in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

You are right that in order to ensure that the elementary operations define a lower triangular matrix, one can only use those that add a multiple of a row to a row *below* it, or that multiply a row by a nonzero scalar (the latter if you allow diagonal entries of $L$ that differ from $1$). The point is that, provided you always find a nonzero coefficient on the diagonal, you never *need* any other operations to transform the matrix into an upper triangular matrix. (In cases where at some point you find a $0$ on the diagonal with some nonzero coefficient below it, no $LU$ decomposition exists at all.)

Comment: thanks for your explanation dear Marc. Honestly I didn't completely get it yet.can you provide me an example please?